# How to replace multiple character in textbox keypress event using vb.net or c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

When i am pressing any key in the textbox it will return "A" Character.

Code sample:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.KeyChar = "A"
End Sub
```

so i want to get multiple character. how to get?

code sample:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.KeyChar = "AB"
End Sub
```

the above coding not working. the e.keychar get only one character that is "A" only return. How to get all the characters.

Comment: `KeyPress` reports that the user pressed a single key. "AB" is not a key, so this won't work. What is it you're trying to accomplish? It is likely that `TextChanged` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append to the TextBox that "AB" and stop the event

```
  var text = sender as TextBox; 
  text.Text = text.Text + "AB";
  e.Handled = true;
```

Or you just can use [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx)

Comment: ok thanks but when you assign the text to textbox that time the cursor position move to first location (i.e) the selectionstart property is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the text box's keypress event, you're substituting whatever key was captured (e.keychar) with the keyChar 'A'.  If you want all keys to come through the text box, remove the code that substitutes 'A' for whatever key was pressed.

Comment out your line of code, in other words, and all keys will pass through to the text box.

Did you want to limit their entry to keys A-Z?